# Sum and conditional in oracle sql

Tags: oracle

Hello I need help on this query
I Have folliwing datas

```
Part   OderQty ShippedQty  QOH
10510   10          5       10
10510   10          0       10
10510   10          0       10
10511   10          10      20
10511   20          0       20
```

I need to filter where the sum of OrderQty - sum of Shipped Qty is < QOH.
Example:

```
Part 10510
total sum Ordered: 30
total sum Shipped: 5
Balance: 25
QOH: 10
```

I need all part where the condition is like part 10510
the second part number is fine because I needed 30, shipped 10 and have 20 on hand, do you how to write this query for oracle,

Thanks
ld

Comment: What SQL have you tried so far?

Comment: Are you guaranteed that the `QOH` for all rows with the same `Part` value will be identical?  If not, which `QOH` value should you use?  If `QOH` is really an attribute of a part, any chance you could fix the data model so that it is properly normalized?

Comment: Yes, QOH is the same for all rows, the because that line is the main header in the part table, the order qty and shipped qty comes from another table where the part could be more than one time, that the reason I using a sun in those two columns...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select part 
from your_table
group by part
having 
  sum(OrderQty) - sum(ShippedQty) < max(QOH)
```

Comment: Thanks, Having was the SOLUTION, LD